# 18.04 Color banding during video playing

Tags: 18.04, video

I recently changed from Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu 18.04.

I am using the following:

- Dell Inspiron  3650 (Intel® Core™ i3-6100 CPU @ 3.70GHz × 4 )
- Radeon RX 550 Series (POLARIS12 / DRM 3.23.0 / 4.15.0-23-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
- Acer 23" LED Technology Monitor

When I was playing this [Youtube clip](https://youtu.be/uLY7phUi2fA?t=1282) (at 21:22) I couldn't help but notice this is what I am seeing some "edged" round lighting at the background, or [color banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding), see screenshot:

[image]

I don't seem to notice that when I am on a Windows 10 machine.

**Edit:**

I tested on the Windows 10 machine, the light in the background is very smooth compared to the one I see in the Ubuntu.

What could the issue be? The driver? Settings? Graphics card?